# Kubernetes health check public access

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-security

Let's say you have microservices and running many nodes. Every nodes expose services to internet and they have also health rest services that are used internally but they should be private.

How do you make private your health checks in Kubernetes ?

Is Kubernetes Ingress Controller only way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself and want to share here.

As I said on the question, It is possible to restrict some urls to outside world in Kubernetes Ingress so they are only active internally.

By the way I am using Google Cloud but it shouldn't be Cloud Provider specific.

Answer (score 0):

Such question depends on the public cloud and the way you created your cluster.
For example in Google cloud the default of every service type is LoadBalancer that expose to the internet automatic.

In Azure for example if you use acs-engine not and when you create a service the default of the service type is ClusterIP (if not configured as LoadBalancer).

Please elaborate more on the public cloud provider and the Kubernetes cluster creation method.